# Administrating Websphere to reinstall the application with a WAR file

Tags: java, websphere, war, ear

I have a web project that takes a WAR file and gets deployed on the Websphere Application server. How do I Administer Websphere(Probably with the help of a script(s)) so that WebSphere takes WAR file copied to the server to reinstall the application with the WAR file automatically. The server is an AIX machine.

I found a script that has the statement

```
    AdminApplication.updateApplicationUsingDefaultMerge( "EAR_FILE",  "EAR_FILE_PATH") 

Will the above statement work only for EAR file, and not WAR file and if so which statement(s) I can use for WAR file?
```

Comment: You don't convert a war file to an ear file. You create an ear file with the required meta data and add the war file to it.

Comment: You also dont need ear as WebSphere supports installation of war files also. So fix your script.

Comment: @Gas I edited the question can you look into it now?

Answer (score 0):

Here are links to Knowledge center, it doesnt matter that it says EAR, same will work for WAR:

- [Install command](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.iseries.doc/ae/txml_callappinstall.html)

  ```
  AdminApp.install('location_of_ear.ear','[-node nodeName -cell cellName -server serverName]')
  ```
- [Update command](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.iseries.doc/ae/rxml_adminapp.html#rxml_adminapp__cmd18)
- [Update example command](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/txml_updatingapp.html)

  ```
  AdminApp.update('app1', 'app', ['-operation', 'update', '-contents', 
    'c:/apps/app1/newApp1.ear', '-usedefaultbindings', '-nodeployejb'])
  ```

Comment: what is app here in the arguments. In the documentation it says content type value.